# Struggling to understand this answer on A=QR factorisation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I think I understand it on a surface level, but not well enough to understand how $r_1$ and $r_2$ was obtained in 2(b). Could someone kindly explain it?

Comment: Please type the question and the answer using MathJax. Only question 2b) is relevant here so you don't need to type up the other parts.

Comment: @TobyMak I agree with writing using MathJax, but I guess the question suggests using part a) to answer b), so it is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following may be an approach to consider:

One is looking to satisfy the following form:

$$
A=QR
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u} & \mathbf{v} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{q}_{1} & \mathbf{q}_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} \\
0 & r_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As stated, because $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are orthogonal, we can use them in $Q$ after normalization:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u} & \mathbf{v} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{u}}}\mathbf{u} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{w}}}\mathbf{w} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} \\
0 & r_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$.

To make the left hand side agree with the right hand side, we need to find the $r_{ij}$ to compensate for the choice of $Q$.

Multiplying out the matrices on the right hand side we have:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u} & \mathbf{v} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{u}}}\mathbf{u} &
r_{12} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{u}}}\mathbf{u} + r_{22} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{w}}} \mathbf{w} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$.

From this, one sees that $r_{11}=\sqrt{\mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{u}}=| \mathbf{u} |$.  From the solution in part (a), one has that

$$
\mathbf{v}=c \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{w}
$$

so we can see that $r_{12}=c\sqrt{\mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{u}}=c| \mathbf{u} |$ and $r_{22}=\sqrt{\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{w}}=| \mathbf{w} |$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the great explaination!

Answer (score 1):

I think matrix notation (if you are familiar with it) is useful here.

The definition of $Q$ being ortogonal is just $Q^\top Q=I$, so the decomposition is equivalent to:
$$
Q^\top\, A=R
$$

Write $Q$ by columns as $Q=\begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix}$ so that:
$$
Q^\top=\begin{bmatrix}q_1^\top \\ q_2^\top\end{bmatrix}
$$
To get $R$ triangular you only need $R_{21}=0$, where $R_{21}=q_2^\top \, u$. This is where (I guess) the question is thought to use part a). Choose $q_2=w$ which is already computed so that it is orthogonal to $u$. But, wait, you also need *orthonormality*. Then, you have to normalize $q_2$ and then find an orthogonal vector... but do not repeat the work! (as I did at first): if $q_2$ is orthogonal to $u$, then $u$ is orthogonal to $q_2$, so the solution is:
$$
q_1=\frac{u}{|u|} \\
q_2=\frac{w}{|w|} \\
R=Q^\top\,A
$$
where $w$ was obtained in a).